# Xor encryption on binary file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, xor

I'm trying to do a simple encryption script in python. I just want to use XOR encryption on binary files.
My script basically looks like :

```
def xor_c ( a ):
    v=''
    for p in a:
        v += chr((ord(p) ^ 0xA8))
    return v
```

The goal of this is just to encrypt each byte individually.
This should work but all tries i made failed.

I first tried with :

```
handler = open("file",'r')
handler2 = open("output",'w')
contents = handler.read()
handler2.write(xor_c(xor_c(contents)))
```

But after execution the two files `file` and `output` were different.
Since the input file was a binary file (what i want), i've changed the script to :

```
handler = open("file",'rb')
handler2 = open("output",'wb')
contents = handler.read()
handler2.write(xor_c(xor_c(contents)))
```

But this didn't change anything at all.
From what it looks like, some couples of bytes are converted in just one byte at the output (maybe because the chars are not ascii, but this should not happen with binary mode ...). Moreover the last byte of the output is `0xA8` (logically got from the conversion of the `\0` at the end of the input file. Considering this i've also changed the `xor_c` function to :

```
def xor_c ( a ):
    v=''
    for p in a:
        v += chr((ord(p) ^ 0xA8))
    return v[:-1]+'\0'
```

To make sure the last character will always be a `\0` but this doesn't work either.

Any suggestions ? remarks ? tips ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer and `handler2` contains exactly the same data as `handler`. By the way: your `xor_c` is highly inefficient. I would create a translation table and use `str.translate` instead.

Comment: If some characters are represented by more than one byte, it may be a unicode file. Python 2.x and 3.x require different approaches, so a statement, which version you use would be helpful.

Comment: @guidot : I'm using python 2.7. @Bakuriu : i don't see how i can use `str.translate()` to recreate why i want.

Comment: Similar XOR decipher implementation in Python 3: [How to decrypt data in binary file by XOR operator using a given key at specific offset?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/11033/12021).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do xor, you don't need `chr()` and `ord()` if you use a `bytearray`.

In fact your function then becomes a one-liner;

```
def xor_c(a):
    return bytearray([b^0xA8 for b in bytearray(a)])
```

And it works fine

```
In [4]: xor_c('Test')
Out[4]: bytearray(b'\xfc\xcd\xdb\xdc')

In [5]: r1 = xor_c('Test')

In [6]: r2 = xor_c(r1)

In [7]: r2
Out[7]: bytearray(b'Test')
```

There is something wrong in your examples. This is the input:
[image: input image]

An this is your output after a double xor:
[image: output]

Note that in some places the "'" gets transformed into an `i` *or* a `j`. This is *not* possible with a plain double xor.

Are you sure you used the code I provided above? Because if I run it on a binary file the twice xor-ed data is equal to the original data:

```
In [1]: def xor_c(a, c=0xA8):
   ...:     return bytearray([b^c for b in bytearray(a)])
   ...: 

In [2]: with open('foo.gz', 'rb') as inf:
    data = inf.read()
   ...:     

In [3]: data2 = xor_c(xor_c(data))

In [4]: cmp(data, data2)
Out[4]: 0
```

When I write the data out to disk and compare it, the files are identical too:

```
In [5]: with open('foo2.gz', 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write(data2)
   ...:     

> ll foo*
-rw-r--r--  1 rsmith  rsmith  - 4049792 Apr 16 13:15 foo2.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 rsmith  rsmith  - 4049792 Apr 16 12:39 foo.gz
> diff foo*
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. Some characters are not the same at the input and the output.

Comment: @ibi0tux: Can you add an example to your question? It really should be the same.

Comment: Here are two screenshots i made by showing contents with `less`. The first is the input file, and the second the output file. (input file: [link](http://www.mirari.fr/MyeY), output file : [link](http://www.mirari.fr/igDI))

Comment: @ibi0tux: Are you sure you used the code I provided? Because that works. See updated answer. What happens with your data is not possible with a double xor.

Comment: I've rewritten the whole code. I finally find out that the bug occurs when using `open` and `close` but does not with the usage of `with`. I really don't understand why.

Comment: @ibi0tux: Please amend your question to show us the _complete_ code for the working and non-working versions.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry I misread the question at first)

I think the problem may lie in `v` initialization: `v` shouldn't be a `string`, but a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray)

```
v = bytearray()
```

I don't have the tools to verify here.

Comment: I've tried with bytearray(), there are changes. Some bytes are now ok, but some others are still mis-converted. That's weird ... I saw in pydoc that `ord()` is able to convert non-ASCII characters. Do you know if is it possible that it is trying to convert several bytes at once (even in a binary mode) ?